# Android emulator stops responding after one interaction

Tags: android, react-native

So I'm using an Android emulator (the stock one) to test out my react native application I'm building.

I can load my app on the emulator using react-native run-android and then my app loads fine. However I can only ever do pretty much one interaction, such as pressing a link, after that my app just doesn't respond and I have to restart my react packager to get it to reload. Are there any reasons why this might be happening and how this can be resolved please, it's making it super hard to develop any project.

There is no strenuous code in place and runs fine on my IOS emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar issues, especially after rebooting the emulator.  I've found that the best solution is to reset the emulator and check the wipe user data box.  You then need to wait until the emulator is fully booted before starting the packager.  This works for me most of the time in 0.14, but isn't foolproof.  I would also check the chrome debugger and make sure there aren't any IOS exclusive parts of the code causing issues, but I'm guessing you've tried that already.

Comment: Yeah I've made sure that there aren't any IOS components which might be breaking things, and React native seem to have a good way of showing error messages for components which aren't compatible anyway. I wasn't sure if it was a RAM problem on my emulator as I can't get it to go higher than 1GB without some errors with the whole HAXM thing. I tried your method and it still renders unresponsive after a short while unfortunately.